# Database connection for online dashboard viewing

Tags: apache-superset

I'm a newbie to creating dashboards, and I'm wondering how dashboards published online are able to be viewed anytime. Would it be a problem to use a database that's stored on my computer to create and publish dashboards on my organization's website? If I turn my computer off/put it to sleep or if the database is not open and running, will people not be able to see the dashboards that would be published online? Thanks!

I tried Googling this and couldn't find an answer. I've also tried connecting SQLite and PostgresSQL to my Superset account to test this but have not had success connecting either of these databases so far.

Comment: hi 
there are many solutions depending on our situation 
what is the dashboard tool you are using? "Power BI, graphana, or other
and do you need the dashboard with live data from DB or just be updated with interval time "like every x hours, day, week, etc

Comment: Hi, I'm thinking of using Apache Superset. I thought this was a Superset forum. I don't need the dashboard to have live data. Updated with interval time is fine. Do you know how that works with Superset? Or with other dashboard tools if the data is stored locally on your computer?